# It seems a stove top coil / burner element defies black body radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, radiation, thermal-radiation

Most glow charts say that incipient red Heat is 1000 Fahrenheit or 540 Celsius , and bright orange is just shy of 2,000 Fahrenheit or 1093 celsius . But my fluke thermocouple rated at over 2,000 Fahrenheit  and thermal imaging tests conclude my element begins to glow a faint red at 600 Fahrenheit or 315 Celsius and is bright orange on maximum heat at 1292 Fahrenheit (700 Celsius ) . is my thermocouple not accurate because , it measures other things very accurate less hot and much hotter ! Is it possible the black body radiation is not applicable to tubular appliance elements Very curious to know ?  thanks .

Comment: What is the emissivity of the element? Is it close to a blackbody, or might it have a different spectrum? Remember, blackbodies are the simplest case, but real objects deviate from them in various ways.